# How to add two images together (green screen system) in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I have two images, one with subject and other one with background. The subject image has green background and I want to remove the green color from subject and add the subject without green color to another background, basically changing the background of one picture with another in LabVIEW without C code or MATLAB code, only using LabVIEW blocks.
So far, I got the following, but I am not getting one thing how to remove a very small portion of pixels. How to solve this problem,
[image: front panel]
[image: block diagram]

Comment: Is the background always the same? If so, then rather search its exact color (RGB combination) and replace that exact color. Or, now you could try to change your condition from "greater" to "greater or equal" (but not sure, b/c I don't have files to test the code).

Comment: Still not working, replaced with greater or equal sign. But green pixel from image are not getting completely fade.

Comment: and did you try to replace pixels by exact color match? Check if image's pixel has the same exact color as background, if so - replace that pixel by new background pixel.

Comment: How to replace those pixels,  here are my files links: https://gofile.io/d/eiYw4W

Comment: The green color is not uniform, pixels are replaced except edges pixels which don't have green pixels  255 exact,  and rest of Red and Blue are not 0, so they are somewhere between 0-255,

Comment: can we use three sliders (knob) to adjust the pixel threshold?

Comment: Not sure that it would help... Maybe, try implement comparison using running average - because the problem is at the borders of "normal" image. So maybe running average could help to "smooth" those borders.

Answer (score 1):

So your algorithm is to replace a pixel, when  `red - blue =0` in the first place.
This condition is true for all this colors:

[image]

While there is no magenta in the picture, there is some almost black below the elbow and some almost white at the hand. So, that's replaced.

Try to restrict the colors to be replaced more, maybe like this:

[image]

Also, I'd to this independently for red and blue. So, for example

`green > A AND red < B AND blue < C AND green-red > D AND green-blue > E`

Since one of your files is names "final lec final.vi", I'd stop here ;-)

Oh, and just for fun: Playing with brightness and contrast reveals the JPEG artifacts, which is one part of the problem:

[image]